# Table row without borders (including leftmost and rightmost)

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I want a specific row in a table completely borderless. (The idea is for a large collection add a symbolic "gap" and continue with deeper data).

I've found the way to set the cells borderless but the table's border still is visible on that row.

One solution could be creating another table below but the problem then is that I'd lose the alignment of columns.

If I set the table without borders then the border-collapse is not effective. *(**Note**: This statement is not true, I leave it because it was in the original post)*

```css
    table, tr, td {
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .empty_row{
      border: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBBB</td>
        <td>CCCC</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>DDD</td>
        <td>EEE</td>
        <td>FFF</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr class='empty_row'>
        <td class='empty_row' colspan='3'>..... (this should have no borders at the sides)</td>
      </tr>
    
      <tr>
        <td>GGGGGGGG</td>
        <td>HHH</td>
        <td>III</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks all for the good responses. I was wrong when saying "If I set the table without borders then the border-collapse is not effective". My fault, when I tried it I was removing also the border-collapse property of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.empty_row{
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBBB</td>
    <td>CCCC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>DDD</td>
    <td>EEE</td>
    <td>FFF</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='empty_row'>
    <td class='empty_row' colspan='3'>.....</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>GGGGGGGG</td>
    <td>HHH</td>
    <td>III</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes but here I don't have the border-collapse

Comment: here you go bro

Comment: Uh, yes, it works, sorry. When testing it I was also invalidating the border-collapse on the table.

Comment: ?? just noticed that your answer turned to be an exact copy of my snippet .... I do not mind you get credits, but not even a line of explanation on what you fixed here :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand your question correctly but hopefully this should get you started.

You can actually just set the left and right borders to transparent. They will take up space which sounds like what you want?

It's important to note that each individual border around a cell is actually a trapezoid, so you will have interestingly shaped triangles at the intersection of each cell which becomes increasingly visible as the border increases.

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr, td {
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBBB</td>
    <td>CCCC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>DDD</td>
    <td>EEE</td>
    <td>FFF</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='empty_row'>
    <td class='empty_row' colspan='3'>.....</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>GGGGGGGG</td>
    <td>HHH</td>
    <td>III</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Removing full table border. Apply border only to Cells

You could take the border off the whole table and place it only on the individual cells. Allowing you to turn on/off specific cells.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* keep border-collapse for table */
}
tr, td {
  border: 2px solid black; /* border applied exclusivly to cells, not whole table */
}
.empty_row {
  border: 0;  /* any cell with this class will have borders removed */
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBBB</td>
      <td>CCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>DDD</td>
      <td>EEE</td>
      <td>FFF</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class='empty_row'>
      <td class='empty_row' colspan='3'>..... (this should have no borders at the sides)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>GGGGGGGG</td>
      <td>HHH</td>
      <td>III</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

### 2. Using CSS transforms

Or using `transform: scaleX()` you could stretch your cell ever so slightly over your border.

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.empty_row {
  background-color: #fff; /* must set background or border shows through */
  transform: scaleX( 1.01 ); /* stretch cell slightly over border. */
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBBB</td>
      <td>CCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>DDD</td>
      <td>EEE</td>
      <td>FFF</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class='empty_row'>
      <td class='empty_row' colspan='3'>..... (this should have no borders at the sides)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>GGGGGGGG</td>
      <td>HHH</td>
      <td>III</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set borders only on `td`.

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.empty_row {
  border: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBBB</td>
    <td>CCCC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DDD</td>
    <td>EEE</td>
    <td>FFF</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='empty_row'>
    <td class='empty_row' colspan='3'>.....</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>GGGGGGGG</td>
    <td>HHH</td>
    <td>III</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```